# Toast notification response in background task

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, toast, background-task

I'm writing an application which can show toast notifications in a background task  *(I use BackgroundTaskBuilder)*. In the notification I'm using two button, which should do two different function, but I can't get the notification's response.

I read on the internet that I should start another background task for this, but I can't start another background task in a backround task.

So my question is: How can I get that the user what button clicked in the notification?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This looks like it might be useful:
http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2016/02/uwp-tips-toast-button.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Windows 10, we can handle a toast notification activation from either foreground or background. In Windows 10, it introduces adaptive and interactive toast notifications which have an `activationType` attribute in `<action>` element. With this attribute, we can specify what kind of activation this action will cause. Using following toast for example:

```xml
<toast launch="app-defined-string">
  <visual>
    <binding template="ToastGeneric">
      <text>Microsoft Company Store</text>
      <text>New Halo game is back in stock!</text>
    </binding>
  </visual>
  <actions>
    <action activationType="foreground" content="See more details" arguments="details"/>
    <action activationType="background" content="Remind me later" arguments="later"/>
  </actions>
</toast>
```

[image]

When user clicks "See more details" button, it will bring the app to foreground. [Application.OnActivated method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.application.onactivated.aspx) will be invoked with a new [activation kind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.activation.iactivatedeventargs.kind.aspx) – [ToastNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.activation.activationkind.aspx). And we can handle this activation like following:

```cs
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the root frame
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    // TODO: Initialize root frame just like in OnLaunched

    // Handle toast activation
    if (e is ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs)
    {
        var toastActivationArgs = e as ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs;

        // Get the argument
        string args = toastActivationArgs.Argument;
        // TODO: Handle activation according to argument
    }
    // TODO: Handle other types of activation

    // Ensure the current window is active
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

When user clicks "Remind me later" button, it will trigger a background task instead of activating the foreground app. So there is no need to start another background task in a background task.

To handle the background activation from toast notifications, we need to create and register a background task. The
background task should be declared in app manifest as **"System event"** task and set its trigger to [ToastNotificationActionTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.toastnotificationactiontrigger.aspx). Then in the background task, use [ToastNotificationActionTriggerDetail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotificationactiontriggerdetail.aspx) to retrieve pre-defined arguments to determine which button is clicked like:

```cs
public sealed class NotificationActionBackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
{
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        var details = taskInstance.TriggerDetails as ToastNotificationActionTriggerDetail;

        if (details != null)
        {
            string arguments = details.Argument;
            // Perform tasks
        }
    }
}
```

For more info, please see [Adaptive and interactive toast notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-adaptive-interactive-toasts), especially [Handling activation (foreground and background)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-adaptive-interactive-toasts#handling-activation-foreground-and-background). And also [the complete sample](https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/quickstart-sending-local-toast-win10) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I understand this, but if I create and show the notification in a background task, how can I start another for the `ToastNotificationActionTrigger`?

Comment: @SüliPatrik You need to add new background task like the `ToastNotificationBackgroundTask` in the [official sample](https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/quickstart-sending-local-toast-win10) and also register the `ToastNotificationBackgroundTask`. Then you can send toast notification in your original background task. For example, let's assume you send a toast just like what in official sample's `ButtonSendToast_Click` method. Then when you click the "Like" button in the toast, the `ToastNotificationActionTrigger` will be triggered. The `ToastNotificationBackgroundTask` will start.

Comment: @SüliPatrik You do not start the `ToastNotificationBackgroundTask` in your original background task, but the user's click on the toast notification starts the `ToastNotificationBackgroundTask` and in this background task, you can know which button user has clicked by using `details.Argument`.