# UWP Background task not able to send Push Notification

Tags: push-notification, uwp

I have a foreground app sending a raw push notification to a background task in another device. When background task receives the notification, it will reply by sending a raw push notification to original foreground app.  My problem is the foreground app never receives any notifications from the background task.

To debug, I made the foreground and background channel ID the same and run both the foreground app and background task on the same windows desktop PC but still the foreground app never receives the push notification from the background task.  The foreground app actually can receive the original message from itself but didn't process it so the background task handled it so I know the foreground app is receiving notifications without issues.  The push notification routine is common in both so I know the code works and the status codes were all successful. So it seems the raw push notification initiated by the background tasks seems to get lost somewhere.

What could be the problems?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Toast notification response in background task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653304/toast-notification-response-in-background-task)

Comment: Mine is not about Toast notification.

Comment: I want to confirm firstly are you using [WNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview)?

Comment: @sunteen Wu, yes I am using WNS.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the task is registered correctly?

And did you check project rome? that can maybe solve this in an easier way?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/connected-apps-and-devices

Comment: The task should be registered correctly as it can receive a push notification. 
 The problem is the push notification the background task sends out just mysteriously vanishes without any errors.  My project is meant for 2 different devices used by 2 different people with 2 different logon ids.